# Combine multiple network interfaces to connect to a dedicated server

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, dedicated-server

this is an underpaid employee writing, who's apparently responsible for all the IT stuff in a very small (non-IT) company. Today said company got a bunch of PCs/workstations, a switch, a computer that's supposed to be used as a router, two DSL connections (each 16 MBit/s downstream and 1 MBit/s upstream) and a dedicated server which is hosted and managed professionally by a larger local company with some decent connection speed (1 GBit/s both directions if I'm not mistaken).

This is what I've set up (note I'm not making use of the second DSL connection at all)...

```
          ETH0                    ETH1
[  SWITCH  ]---[LINUX DEBIAN ROUTER]---[DSL MODEM 1]---[INTERNET]
 |   |   |
PC1  |   |
    PC2  |
        ...
```

... when my boss asked me, if it was somehow possible to get 32 MBit/s downstream and 2 MBit/s upstream. At that time I replied "no" without thinking too much about it. Now I've just had the following idea...

```
                                  ETH1                                             ETH0
          ETH0                     ,---[DSL MODEM 1 (NON-STATIC IP)]---,        ,---,                  ETH0
[  SWITCH  ]---[LINUX DEBIAN ROUTER]                                   [INTERNET]   [LINUX DEBIAN SERVER]---[INTERNET]
 |   |   |                         '---[  DSL MODEM 2 (STATIC IP)  ]---'        '---'
PC1  |   |                        ETH2                                             ETH0
    PC2  |
        ...
```

... but I have absolutely no clue how to implement that. Would that even be possible? What would the masquerading rules look like on the router? What about the server? I didn't find anything on the internet, mainly because I couldn't come up with any good keywords to search for to begin with. English obviously isn't my first language.

Thanks in advance for your time!

**Edit** I stumbled across the keyword "bonding". Is it applicable in this situation?

Comment: A friend of mine achieved this. For that purpose, he was force to mount N vpn (for N connection, in your case 2) toward the server. Can't get you much more info, sorry.

Comment: This would be very interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in a YouTube video. It's done the way aif has suggested.
[Do it Yourself: Bonding Over VPN](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hp7Rv2tevWk)

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html) should cover what you're trying to achieve. You should be able to update the routing tables with scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` (add route when interface goes up) and `/etc/network/if-down.d/` (delete route when interface goes down).

Comment: We didn't get a fixed IP network assigned for one of the two connections. The IP address changes every time when reconnecting to the internet.

Comment: Then you need to update the routing tables every time you reconnect to the internet.